# Is it possible to change the category of an out of the box web part?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, web-part, out-of-the-box

I have customized an out of the box web part (for example a content query web part found in the "content rollup" category in Sharepoint 2013) and when I add it to a SharePoint page, I want it to show under a different category.

Is it possible to do such a thing ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes , you can , but it's not preferred to do this with a build in web part.

**Steps**

- Go to Root Site > Site Setting > Site app permissions
  Web Designer Galleries > Web Part .
- Check your web Part (if not there upload it) > click on edit button at edit column
- Below Group section  > Specify your own value:

[image]